# Displaying decrementing value of a primary key

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub TblCustomerBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.TblCustomerBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.CustomerDataDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CustomerDataDataSet.tblCustomer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblCustomerTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CustomerDataDataSet.tblCustomer)

End Sub

Private Sub btnRegister_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
    Try
        TblCustomerBindingSource.EndEdit()
        TblCustomerTableAdapter.Update(CustomerDataDataSet.tblCustomer)
        MessageBox.Show("Registered successfully!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Form5.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        Form5.TblReservationBindingSource.AddNew()
        Form5.Label2.Text = Customer_IDTextBox.Text
        Form5.Label3.Text = FirstNameTextBox.Text & " " & LastNameTextBox.Text
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    FirstNameTextBox.Text = ""
    LastNameTextBox.Text = ""
    Contact_NoTextBox.Text = ""
    Email_AddressTextBox.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Date_Of_RegistrationTextBox.Text = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt")
End Sub
```

When I try to add a new record vb.net automatically display the primary key in a decrementing value but when I click register and check my ms access file it displays the correct value for my primary key.

[Here's my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYgQH.jpg)

Comment: And the error is .... ?

Comment: @Jaxedin Instead of displaying the correct primary key from my ms access, For example: 1, it displays -1 on vb.net when I try to add a new entry.

Comment: On a new object, a primary key will be always -1. Primary key will be assigned after inserting to a DB. You can hide that value on a new entry.

Comment: @Jaxedin owh okay. Thanks!